# What can you use in cookie dough as a binding agent other than eggs or sugar?

Tags: baking, cookies, pastry, baking-soda

Most recipes for cookies (oatmeal or chocolate chip) contain eggs or somthing sweet. By "somthing sweet" I mean corn syrup, maple syrup, honey, agave necter, and/or sugar.

Suppose you had to make cookies for a vegan diabetic person (no eggs), but you do not want the cookies to be dry or hard. You need some kind of binding agent which makes the cookies pliable (soft and flexible) and makes the cookies softly chewy.

The following is a recipe somone else gave me, but I removed all of the corn syrup and eggs.I do not know what substitute for syrup and eggs would make the cookie soft and flexible.

| number | unit | ingredient |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cup. | butter |
| 1+1/4 | cup. | flour |
| 1/2 | tea spoon | baking soda |
| 1 | tea spoon | salt |
| 3 | cup. | oats |
| 1. | cup. | nuts (walnuts, peanuts, pecans etc...) |

The nuts are optional and are for better flavor.

Comment: If this is supposed to be vegan, shouldn't you also be replacing the butter?

Comment: There are a LOT of recipes out there for vegans, diabetics, celiacs, etc.  Unless you’re trying to recreate someone’s favorite recipe from their childhood, it’s often better to just search the Internet for a recipe that’s specifically made for the issue you’re trying to deal with.

Comment: be aware: diabetic means probably no white flour, not just no sugar.